# Conformal transformation of metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, conformal-geometry

Let us define the following metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$:
$$ g|_v(X, Y) := e^{-|v|^2} \langle X, Y\rangle,$$
where the brackets denote the standard scalar product.

How does the resulting manifold look like? If $n=2$, can it be isometrically embedded in $3$-space?

It has finite volume, but is it geodesically complete?

Comment: what is v in your expression?

Answer (score 2):

It is not geodesically complete.

Any ray that begins at the origin is clearly the image of a geodesic. Since each one of those rays has a finite length with respect to $g$, geodesics are not defined at infinite time.